SwiftEmitModule normal arm64 Emitting\ module\ for\*** SwiftCompile normal arm64 Compiling\ ***.swift
SwiftEmitModule normal arm64 Emitting\ module\ for*** SwiftCompile normal arm64 Compiling\ ***.swift Getting this error on terminal but able to build with xcode
Running in Mac M1 chip
xcodebuild build -project .xcodeproj -scheme " - Prod" -destination 'generic/platform=iOS'
Expected above command should build the projec
xcodebuild build -project .xcodeproj -scheme " - Prod" -destination 'generic/platform=iOS'
while running this we are getting above error

Please include more data from the error message, setup, etc. Look at other questions of this sort on SO for examples.

Did you resolve this issue?
